# While user manual inputs date into text input, how do I format the date to add slashes and put the input at the end (e.g. 08/21/2013)?

Tags: angularjs

While the user inputs numeric values for a date input, what would be the best approach to add in slashes?  E.g. user inputs

```
0
08
*code fires to add in slash*
08/
08/2
08/21
*code fires to add in slash
08/21/2
08/21/20
08/21/201
08/21/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

a regex on the input ng-model, being watched, and modified by the $watch callback

Comment: Interesting idea... I'll look into  making this today.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using standard HTML5 form element for data input: `input[type="date"]` it has built-in support for delimiters. And it's more browser-friendly.

I've created a simple directive to enable it to work correctly with AngularJS ~1.2.16.

Please look here for details:
https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-date

And here's the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/F2LcY/1/

Hope it helps!